# How to start IPython Notebook with a specified namespace

Tags: ipython

I have an GUI-based (TraitsUI/PyQt/Envisage) application written in Python. I would like to spawn an IPython Notebook in which I expose a small API and a number of objects. Those objects include a SQLAlchemy session and a bunch of SQLAlchemy models.

I've looked a lot, but I can't find any examples of this. I can start a notebook:

```
from IPython.frontend.html.notebook import notebookapp
app = notebookapp.NotebookApp.instance()
app.initialize()
app.start()
```

and that works well enough (although I'd prefer if 'start' was nonblocking... I assume I can do it in another thread if needed), but I can't alter the namespace.

I've also found examples like this:

```
from IPython.zmq.ipkernel import IPKernelApp

namespace = dict(z=1010)

kapp = IPKernelApp.instance()
kapp.initialize()

# Update the ns we want with special variables auto-created by the kernel
namespace.update(kapp.shell.user_ns)
# Now set the kernel's ns to be ours
kapp.shell.user_ns = namespace

kapp.start()
```

But I'm not sure how to actually open the Notebook from here.

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: The Notebook server and Kernel are necessarily in different processes.

You would embed the Kernel in your namespace exactly as in other cases, but the Notebook server would need to be modified to be able to connect to existing kernels.

Comment: Or you could use a `Config` object to set the `kernel_cmd` trait to run the required code to generate the required namespace, when the kernel is started.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import IPython
>>> z=1010
>>> IPython.embed()
Python 3.5.2 (default, Oct  8 2019, 13:06:37)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.9.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: z
Out[1]: 1010
```